# Should questions with answers obvious to experienced programmers be closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

We all see lots of questions where the answer is

- you didn’t initialize that counter to 0
- that pointer was not initialized to NULL
- your if(!(a==10 || x= 11)) logic is inside out
- .....

If the poster has provided full compilable source code and a reasonable description I don’t think these questions should be closed with "typo or not reproducible".

Just because the answer is obvious to experienced developers doesn’t mean it’s obvious to the poster. Otherwise they wouldn't have posted it.

In fact, even downvotes seem unfair if the question is clear and has full source. The poster has fully obeyed the rules, and done exactly what SO is for.

Comment: I think all 3 of these are likely dupes. The last I'm almost certain is. _Maybe_ they shouldn't be closed as typos or _unlikely to help future readers_, although I wouldn't argue if they were, but if a dupe can be find they should be closed as dupes.

Comment: close as dup is fine, if a reasonably smart OP can be expected to deduce from the dupe what the error is. I often look at the dups too and they really dont help, its quite often a kneejerk

Comment: Completely agree with you on the downvote point... yes, the question is easily solved. Yes, the OP will probably be making the  face. But if there's everything in the question required to understand and answer it, they don't deserve to be punished

Comment: *"In fact even downvotes seem unfair if the question is clear, has full source."* - but is it *useful*? Not to the OP, but to the Q&A repository. That's the question.

Comment: Often, a suitable dup for those questions would say 'you are unable to program computers because you don't know how to debug.  This is what you should have tried before posting your question......'.  It is depressing that so many such posters do not try even a few extra print statements, never mind use an actual debugger.  So many 'my program does not work even though it builds with no errors', as if that is unusual:(   I feel like just downvoting/closing because the OP's start programming and then just stop part-way, expecting others to do the grunt work of debug/retest. I just despair.....

Comment: Question #3 is absolutely a dupe... my highest-rated answer addresses an almost identical question.

Answer (score 25):

Questions with obvious answers should not be closed. They should be answered. However, if they have obvious answers, don't we already have existing answers on this site? Please close them as duplicates.

Some questions are closed as typos because the resolution is unlikely to help anyone else. It's often localized to that specific code. Or the problem description states the issue is something entirely different. Use your own judgement when voting to close. Some easy questions can become good canonical that you can later use to close similar questions against.

Comment: *the problem description states the issue is something entirely different.* Indeed! Dupe hammering an XY problem may require a comment or even a short answer that explains how the answers in the dupe target apply to the new question.

Comment: Observations: a) closing is seen as a punishment b) downvotes are definitely punishment (think of rep 1 users). Is the aim of SO to help new devs or provide a library of useful dev info?. I thought that was decided in the great split, its meant to  be a helpful place for new devs

Comment: I miss the old _"too localised"_ close option 

Comment: @pm100 The original author's feelings don't really matter that much. SO is not a free help desk. If they take moderation activities personally, it's their problem. Neither closure nor downvotes are meant to be a punishment. We're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.

Comment: downvotes subtract rep, and rep is needed to do certain things, so its definitely a punishment.

Comment: @pm100 Downvoting answers costs rep too and it's definitely not a punishment. Reputation is only needed if you want to do more moderation activities. Thus receiving negative reputation for reducing content quality by posting poor questions is the desired effect. Either way, users cast votes to rate the content. The system then might take away reputation points from the author. This should not stop you from rating content.

Comment: In summary, do what benefits the site in the long run, not what benefits the poster of a single question.

Comment: What about the feelings of the answerers who continually have to look up and link the sand FAQ dupes over, and over, and over again?  That sounds more like a punishment than a few downvotes.

Comment: @pm100 1 rep users actually don't suffer anything if they receive downvotes (apart from getting closer to a question/answer ban). If a user has 1 rep and receives a downvote they don't end up with -1 reputation, they remain on 1 reputation. I frequently see 1 rep users end up with 9/11 reputation from a question with a score of -4 because the ("welcoming") upvote was made after the (majority of) downvotes. They got "*rewarded*" for a poor quality question, not "punished". Downvotes are never punishment, they are for content rating, and they are telling future readers the content is poor.

Comment: [*sand* reference](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: @PeterMortensen lol, actually a predictive text cockup - I meant 'same' :))